# Polynomial problem using sets from $\mathbb Q[X]$

Tags: polynomials

Does someone have ideas on this problem? Thank you so much for helping!

> Let $n \in \mathbb N^*$ and $f \in \mathbb Q[x], deg(f) = n$ with property:
>
> $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \in \mathbb Z$, $\forall 0 \leq b < a \leq n (b,a \in \mathbb N)$.
>
> Show:
>
> $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \in \mathbb Z$, $\forall b,a \in \mathbb Z (b \neq a)$.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: A new answer, corresponding better to the OP’s stated expectations.

First, we use the following lemma: if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, such that $f$ is an integer at $n+1$ consecutive points, then $f$ is a linear combination with integer coefficients of $\binom{X}{k}$, $0 \leq k \leq n$.

Second, we use induction on $n$. Show that we can assume $f(0)=0$, then that $f$ is a linear combination with integer coefficients of the $\binom{X}{k}$, $k \leq n$.

Let $\alpha$ be the coefficient of $P_n=\binom{X}{n}$ of $f$. Show that you can apply the induction hypothesis to $f-\alpha P_n$ and thus assume that $f=\alpha P_n$.

Show that $\alpha$ is divisible by $n$.

Show as in the old answer that $Q(a,b)$ mod $\mathbb{Z}$ depends only on $a-b$ and conclude.

Old answer:

We use induction over $n$. If $n \leq 1$, the statement is clear ($n=0$ and $f$ is constant; $n=1$ and $f$ is affine with $\alpha=f(1)-f(0) \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=\alpha$).

Assume that the statement holds whenever $\deg{f} < n$ for some fixed $n \geq 2$. Assume that $\deg{f} =n$. Then $g(X)=f(X+1)-f(X)$ has rational coefficients and degree $n-1$ and satisfies the hypothesis. By induction hypothesis, for all $a \neq b$, $Q(a+1,b+1):=\frac{f(a+1)-f(b+1)}{a-b} \in \mathbb{Z}+Q(a,b)$.

By “induction”, for each $c,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $a \neq b$, $Q(a+c,b+c) \in \mathbb{Z} + Q(a,b)$. For given $a,b$ we can find a $c$ such that $0 \leq a+c,b+c \leq n$. Hence $Q(a+c,b+c)$ is an integer thus $Q(a,b)$ is an integer.

Comment: Are you sure you can find such a $c$ if $\left|a-b\right| > n$ ?

Comment: Oh. How very stupid of me, indeed. I’m editing.

Comment: @Mindlack $Q$ is $g$, right?

Comment: @Olivier Roche: no. $Q$ is a two-variable function.

Comment: @Mindlack Oops, I missed the double column, sorry...

Comment: Why can you apply the induction hypothesis to $f-\alpha P_n$ ?

Comment: Because it has degree $\leq n-1$ and has the sane values as $f$ at $0, \ldots, n-1$.

Comment: Ah! Nice argument. I still don't get the last part of your proof (I cannot extract any use from the old answer), but I have an alternative. Not only is $\alpha$ divisible by $n$; actually, $\alpha$ is divisible by each $g \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ (just apply the assumption to $a = n-g$ and $b=n$). Now, it remains to prove that $b-a\mid \alpha P_n\left(b\right) - \alpha P_n\left(a\right)$ for all $a, b$. Equivalently, it remains to prove that $m\mid \alpha P_n\left(b\right) - \alpha P_n\left(a\right)$ for any positive integer $m$ and any ...

Comment: ... integers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $a \equiv b \mod m$. Equivalently, it remains to prove that $m \mid \alpha P_n\left(a+m\right) - \alpha P_n\left(a\right)$ for any integer $a$. But $P_n\left(a+m\right) = \dbinom{a+m}{n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{a}{k} \dbinom{m}{n-k}$ by the Chu-Vandermonde identity. Subtracting $P_n\left(a\right)$ from this sum just removes its $k=n$ addend. Hence, it remains to prove that $m \mid \alpha \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \dbinom{a}{k} \dbinom{m}{n-k}$. Of course, it suffices to show ...

Comment: ... that $m \mid \alpha \dbinom{m}{n-k}$ for each $k \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$. But $\alpha$ is divisible by $n-k$ (since $\alpha$ is divisible by each $g \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$). Hence, it suffices to show that $m \mid \left(n-k\right) \dbinom{m}{n-k}$. But this follows from $\left(n-k\right) \dbinom{m}{n-k} = m \dbinom{m-1}{n-k-1}$.

Comment: That’s a nice way to end the proof. To explain my argument: let us define $Q(a,b)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. We can apply the induction hypothesis to $g(X)=f(X+1)-f(X)$, which entails that $Q(a+1,b+1)-Q(a,b)$ is an integer for all $a,b$. So it just remains to show that $Q(k,0)$ is always an integer. Now, $Q(k,0)=\frac{\alpha}{n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}$, and $n|\alpha$, QED.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following polynomial?
$$S := \sum_{0 \leqslant a < b \leqslant n} \frac{f}{b-a}$$

The point is that

- $S = q\cdot f$ for $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. In fact, $$q=\sum_{0 \leqslant a < b \leqslant n} \frac{1}{b-a}$$
- for all $a,b$ with  $0 \leqslant a < b \leqslant n, \, S(b)-S(a) \in \mathbb{Z} $

> **(edit)wrong idea** If we knew that $S(a) = S(b)$ for all $0\leqslant a < b \leqslant n$, then, since $S$ is of degree $n$, $S$ would be constant,
>   hence $f$ would be constant.

**a new hope**
The hope is that there is a constant $c\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all 
$0\leqslant a < b \leqslant n$, $\frac{S(b)-S(a)}{b-a} = c$. Then since the polynomial $S - cX$, which is of degree $\leqslant n$, has $n+1$ roots, we would have $S-cX=0$.